# What's the best way to share methods between 2 classes, where I can freely call the methods from either, without using inheritance?

Tags: php, oop

Assume **yourMethod** is a method you provide in your class. 
Assume **packageMethod** is a method provided from my package (note: I'm using Laravel and a facade on the package, but it's probably irrelevant for my question).

How would you best accomplish this:

```
// Controller

$obj = EasyPackage::make(new YourClass);
$obj->easyMethod(); // Calls package method (probably does some stuff using the injected instance of YourClass and some of your methods)
$obj->yourMethod(); // You can still call your methods directly too! But How???

//$obj->yourInstance->yourMethod();  I don't want you to have to do this.
```

Basically these classes are sharing methods without the need for me to explicitly reference the property holding Your instance, as you see commented at the bottom of this example. Instead, EasyPackage should check to see if the method is public and available, first within it's own set of methods, and if not then secondly check YourClass. **How do I get this to work? Is there a proper design pattern that does this that I can research?**

I'm aware that I could probably achieve this using `__call` magic method in the package, but before I go down that road I wanted to make sure I'm not missing some other more standard approach. If the magic method is indeed the best for accomplishing this then I'm interested in seeing it used in a clean way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) or [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

Although in your example I think it is __call method, which in the easiest example can be:

```
public function __call($method, $arguments) {
  return call_user_func_array(array($this->innerObject, $method), $arguments);
}
```

Comment: Should I do a check here to see if the method exists in the outerObject first, and if not found then do `call_user_func_array` on the innerObject?

Comment: Just read up more on `__call`. It appears it's called when a method is unrecognized, so this is perfect.

Comment: Yes this is how __call works. You may also consider __get and __set.